# Why Nested Objects is retrieved from JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two tables, the first one called regions and it has `"region_id"`,`"region_name"`, and the second table is called cities and it has `"city_id"`,`"city_name"`,`"region_id"` as FK,

Now when i tried to pull all cities i hit

> /cities

```
//CityController
@RestController
public class City {
    @Autowired
    private CityService cityService;


    @GetMapping(value = "/cities")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<CityEntity> getCities() {
        List<CityEntity> list = cityService.getCities();
        return list;
    }
}
```

CityEntity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
@Getter
@Setter
public class CityEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "city_name", unique = true)
    private String cityName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id")
    private RegionEntity region;

}
```

and RegionEntity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "regions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class RegionEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "region_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "region_name", unique = true)
    private String regionName;
}
```

and the response was

> [
>       {
>           "id": 1,
>           "cityName": "amman",
>           "region": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "regionName": "part1"
>           }
>       },
>       {
>           "id": 2,
>           "cityName": "zarqa",
>           "region": {
>               "id": 1,
>               "regionName": "part1"
>           }
>       } ]

So far so good

I wanted another API that can pull all regions with their cities so i did something like cityEntity which is i added the bellow method to reagionEntity

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<CityEntity> cities;
```

but Surprisingly when i rehit

> /cities
>   i got `Unexpected ''` but when i hit it in chrome browser it listed a lot of object like `[{"id":1,"regionName":"part1","cities":[{"id":1,"cityName":"amman","region":{"id":1,"regionName":"part1","cities":[{"id":1,"cityName":"amman","region":{"id":1,"regionName":"part1","cities":`

it seems that it repeated itself i have no idea why and nothing helped me in spring.io website

My Repository is extending JPARepository and i used `findAll()` method.
Please advice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 looks like a recursion, op is using boot and the built in Jackson should be able to catch the recursion. More reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, i need both, if i hit for cities it should return them with regions ids, and if i need to hit for regions it should display all regions with it's cities :/

Comment: May be you need to write some more here like , first fetch all the regions and iterate over list and fetch cities for each region similialy  for cities as well.